# Price column object to int in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a column called amount with holds values that look like this: $3,092.44 when I do `dataframe.dtypes()` it returns this column as an object how can i convert this column to type int?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

in regex `\D` means not digit... so we can use [**`pd.Series.str.replace`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

```
dataframe.amount.replace('\D', '', regex=True).astype(int)

0    309244
1    309244
Name: amount, dtype: int64
```

Comment: thank you for this answer can you please help me with my latest question; I dont know how to do it and youre the only one that seems to be able to help! please, thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44475995/remove-blacklisted-emails-pandas-type-error-returned

Answer (score 20):

You can use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) or [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data={'amount':['$3,092.44', '$3,092.44']})
print (dataframe)
      amount
0  $3,092.44
1  $3,092.44

dataframe['amount'] = dataframe['amount'].replace('[\$\,\.]', '', regex=True).astype(int)

print (dataframe)
   amount
0  309244
1  309244
```

note: if output gives back an error of $\ recognized try to remove the slash "" like the following

```
dataframe["amount"] = dataframe["amount"].replace("[$,.]", "", regex=True).astype(int)
```

---

```
dataframe['amount'] = dataframe['amount'].astype(int)

print (dataframe)
   amount
0  309244
1  309244
```

Answer (score 15):

This is how you do it while also discarding the cents:

```
car_sales["Price"] = car_sales["Price"].str.replace('[\$\,]|\.\d*', '').astype(int)
```

Comment: Need to specify regex as True as follows: `car_sales["Price"] = car_sales["Price"].str.replace('[\$\,]|\.\d*', '', regex=True).astype(int)`

Answer (score 3):

```
dataframe["amount"] = dataframe["amount"].str.replace('[\$\,\.]', '').astype(int)
```

```
        Make     Colour    Odometer (KM)        Doors              Price
0       Toyota   White     150043                4                 $4,000.00
1       Honda    Red       87899                 4                 $5,000.00
2       Toyota   Blue      32549                 3                 $7,000.00
3       BMW      Black     11179                 5                 $22,000.00
4       Nissan   White     213095                4                 $3,500.00
5       Toyota   Green     99213                 4                 $4,500.00
6       Honda    Blue      45698                 4                 $7,500.00
7       Honda    Blue      54738                 4                 $7,000.00
8       Toyota   White     60000                 4                 $6,250.00
9       Nissan   White     31600                 4                 $9,700.00
```

```
car_sales["Price"].dtype
output-dtype('O')

car_sales["Price"]=car_sales["Price"].str.replace('[\$\,\.]', '').astype(int)
car_sales["Price"]
```

output:

```
0     400000
1     500000
2     700000
3    2200000
4     350000
5     450000
6     750000
7     700000
8     625000
9     970000
Name: Price, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way to do it:

```
cars["amount"] = cars["amount"].str.replace("$" , "").str.replace("," , "").astype("float").astype("int")
```

1. First you remove the dollar sign
2. Next you remove the comma
3. Then you convert the column to float. If you try to convert the column straight to integer, you will get the following error: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
4. Finally you convert the column to integer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your column name is `amount`, here is what you should do:

```
dataframe['amount'] = dataframe.amount.str.replace('\$|\.|\,', '').astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert a price into string then you can use the below method:

```
car_sales["Price"] = car_sales["Price"].replace('[\$\,]', '').astype(str)

car_sales["Price"]

0     400000
1     500000
2     700000
3    2200000
4     350000
5     450000
6     750000
7     700000
8     625000
9     970000
Name: Price, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import pandas as pd
    
pd.read_csv('car-sales.csv')
    
car_sales['Price']=car_sales['Price'].str.replace('$','',regex=False).str.replace(',','',regex=False).astype(float).astype(int)
# Initially the code removes all the dollar signs and commas.
# Then it converts the string type values into float type values (the code can't directly convert the string type values into int type values).
# And then finally it converts the float type values into int type values
```

The original data behind this code is:[image]

The output data is:[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set it to Int by:

```
df['amount'] = df['amount'].astype(np.int)
```

If you want to tell Python to read the column as Int at first place, use:

```
#assuming you're reading from a file
pd.read_csv(file_name, dtype={'amount':np.int32})
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also work:  `dframe.amount.str.replace("$","").astype(int)`

Answer (score 0):

This should be simple, just by replacing `$`, commas(`,`), and decimals (`.` dots) with nothing (`''`) and removing extra zeros, it would work.

```
your_column_name = your_column_name.str.replace('[\$\,]|\.\d*', '').astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using lambda and ignoring $ is also better solution

```
dollarizer = lambda x: float(x[1:-1])
dataframe.amount = dataframe.amount.apply(dollarizer)
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid extra ZEROs while converting object to int. you should convert the object ($3,092.440) to float using following code:

**Syntax:**

```
your_dataframe["your_column_name"] = your_dataframe["your_column_name"].str.replace('[\$\,]', '').astype(float)
```

**Example:**

```
car_sales["Price"] = car_sales["Price"].replace('[\$\,]', '').astype(float)
```

**Result:**

```
4000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dataframe["amount"] = dataframe["amount"].str.replace('[$,.]|..$','',regex=True).astype(int)

in str.replace(...)

[$,.] mean find $ , .
| mean or

..$ mean find any last 2 character

so '[$,.]|..$' mean find $ , . or any last 2 character
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export_car_sales["Price"] = export_car_sales["Price"].replace('[\$\,\.]', '', regex=True).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one:

```
car_sales["Price"] = car_sales["Price"].str.replace('[\$\,]|\.\d*', '').astype(int)
```

but you have to divide it by 100 to remove the additional zeros that are going to be created, so you will have to run this additional instruction:

```
car_sales["Price"]=car_sales["Price"].apply(lambda x: x/100)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above code we have to use `float` instead of `integer` so that the cent value would be remain as cents.

```
df['Price'] = df['Price'].str.replace('[\$\,]','').astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```py
car_sales = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdbourke/zero-to-mastery-ml/master/data/car-sales.csv")
car_sales["Price"] = car_sales["Price"].replace("[\$\,\.]", "", regex=True).map(lambda x: str(x)[:-2]).astype(int)
car_sales
```

Comment: This assumes that prices objects that happen to be integers explicitely have ",00" digits for cents.

Comment: @OCa - which they do.

Answer (score 0):

```
car_sales["Price"] = car_sales["Price"].replace('[\$\,]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this problem, using or not using regex, which is a parameter that specifies whether or not you will use a regular expression, in our case ("`[\$\,\.]`").
In the first case you will not use regex, which makes the code a little more verbose:

```
data_frame['Price'] = data_frame['Price'].str.replace('$', '').str.replace(',', '').str.replace('.', '')

data_frame["Price"] = data_frame["Price"].astype(int)
```

In the second case we use regex but we need to activate it and use the regular expression:

```
data_frame["Price"] = data_frame["Price"].str.replace('[\$\,\.]', '', regex=True).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
car_sales["Price"] = car_sales["Price"].replace('[\$,]', '', regex=True).astype(float).astype(int)
```

car_sales

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Comment: So it's necessary to convert to float before converting to int?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, you can use a raw string by prefixing the string literal with r. This will ensure that backslashes are interpreted as literal characters and won't be treated as escape sequences

```
car_sales['Price'] = car_sales['Price'].replace(r'[\$\,\.]', '', regex=True).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression [^\d.] will match any character that is not a digit (\d) or a period (.). Then, you can proceed with converting the resulting values to integer type.

```
car_sales['Price'] = car_sales['Price'].replace(r'[^\d\.]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
```